# WinInet upload file PHP

Tags: php, c++, wininet

I have the following problem, I am new to how to send images through Wininet.dll.

I am working with metatrader 4, (C Language) and I have a connection to PHP which is successful, but I am not receiving the attached file on the server.

Annex the codes:

METATRADER 4:

```
string frmdata = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\descarga.png\"\r\nContent-Type: "+filetype+"\r\n\r\nfile contents  here\r\n-------------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\n";
string hdrs = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858";
#import  "Wininet.dll"
      int HttpOpen = InternetOpenW(InternetAgent, Internet_Open_Type_Direct, "0", "0", "0");
      int HttpConnect = InternetConnectW(HttpOpen, "Localhost", 8080, "", "", 3, 0, 1);
      int HttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(HttpConnect, "POST", "/ConnectMT4/funcphp/screenpost.php", "HTTP/1.1", "", acceptTypes, 0, 1);
      bool result = HttpSendRequestW(HttpRequest, hdrs, StringLen(hdrs), frmdata, StringLen(frmdata));
      int read[1];
      Print("This is the POST result: ", result);
      InternetCloseHandle(HttpOpen);
      InternetCloseHandle(HttpRequest);
     }
   return(res==200);
  }
```

**PHP file:**

```
<?php
$desprendible = $_FILES["uploadedfile"];

if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] != null) {
echo "Tiene datos La variable";
}else{
echo "No hay datos";
}
?>
```

The PHP code, I have been trying different codes, this is the last one I have. Attachment photo of the debug of the PHP file: https://prnt.sc/1mm1oh1

Comment: Please share more details. The given code does not look related to PHP to me after all

Comment: I could already make it connect, but now in the PHP file it does not detect anything
https://prnt.sc/1m9i4su
rename the variable:
https://prnt.sc/1m9k0iz

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not detect anything"? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: You use POST in .dll and GET in PHP. Can this be the problem? And where is 'order' specified in .dll?

Comment: I see that error, it is a code that I found on the internet, I am testing it.

Change the method in PHP to $ _POST ['uploadedfile'], but still no information is received. @user1086500